# Adição de mascara de formatação em label de chart no JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper

Tenho um `chart` de linhas e no eixo X ele exibe uma série de datas.
O que quero fazer é  exibir data no seguinte padrão: `dd/MM/yyyy`
pois o mesmo esta exibindo no formato: `yyyy-MM-dd`. Sujestões?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não seria melhor tratar direto no java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direto pelo Jasper adicione na propriedade do seu label :

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($F{sua data})
```

Via Java :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String dataFormatada = null;

dataFormatada = formatter.format("sua data hora");
```

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou!

Comment: hehe,De nada! @JulioCesardaSilvaBarros